# Is the sequence $\{\frac {(-1)^n}{2n}\}$ convergent? If so, what is the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It is an exercise question in my textbook.

**Question**: Is the sequence $\{\frac {(-1)^n}{2n}\}$ convergent? If so, what is the limit? 
$|\{\frac {(-1)^n}{2n}\}-0|=|\{\frac {(-1)^n}{2n}\}| < \varepsilon$

I don't know what to do from here.  Could you give some hint??

Comment: What is the **definition** of a sequence converging to 0, already (since obviously you know, or were told, that the limit is supposed to be 0)?

Comment: Do the braces $\{\;\}$ just show that this is a sequence?  If so, leave them out of your computations ... $|\frac {(-1)^n}{2n}-0|=|\frac {(-1)^n}{2n}| < \varepsilon$

Comment: Even the series converges here so the sequence must converge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):-\frac1{2n}\leqslant\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}\leqslant\frac1{2n}$.

Comment: This is based on results that are **less** elementary than the trouble the OP has.

Comment: Oops, I see the OP now chose to accept your answer. Congratulations, I guess. (At the same time, I have a hunch that this stunning move does not invalidate my first comment in the least... :-))

Comment: @Did Indeed, it doesn't. I felt that the OP wasn't really interested in a proof from the definition of limit. It turns out that I was right, but your first comment is also right.

Comment: Well summarized (afaiac, I see no way they can turn your hint into an proof, from what they showed of their skill level). And the comedy will continue...

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}\right|\le \frac{1}{2n}$$ and $$\frac{1}{2n}$$ tends to zero if $n$ tends to infinity.